# Gulp runSequence running in parallel

Tags: gulp, run-sequence

I have the following Gulp `runSequence` task:

```
gulp.task('test', () => runSequence('test:unit', 'test:e2e'));
```

When the two tasks are:

```
gulp.task('test:unit', () => gulp.start('jasmine'));
gulp.task('test:e2e', () => runSequence('webdriver:update', 'protractor'));
```

Those commands are running in parallel (Jasmine and the other two).

If I change this to be:

```
gulp.task('test', () => runSequence('jasmine', 'test:e2e'));
```

It is working ok (serially)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[`orchestrator.start()`](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator#orchestratorstarttasks-cb) (and therefore `gulp.start()`) is asynchronous. That means you need to signal [async completion](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support) in your `test:unit` task:

```
gulp.task('test:unit', (done) => gulp.start('jasmine', done));
```